# Tkinter Spinbox changes its values after insert

Tags: python, tkinter

once again I am struggeling with Tkinter's spinboxes. I use this (abreviated) code snippet:

```
self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.signposts) - 1, command=lambda: self._select_event(self.event_type,   self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))        
self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.config(state="normal")
self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.insert(0, str(id))
self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.config(state="readonly")
```

The full _edit_event method looks like:

```
def _select_event(self, type, id):
    """ Selects an event for editing its properties """
    if not self._can_draw(): return
    if type != self.event_type:
        #Destroy all widgets on the frame and build those neccessary
        for widget in self.event_edit_widgets: widget.grid_remove()
        self.event_edit_widgets = []
        self.event_type = type
        if self.event_type == "Person": #Build widgets for person
            if len(self.map.persons) <= id: return
            self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.persons) - 1, command=lambda: self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
        elif self.event_type == "Warp": #Build widgets for warp
            if len(self.map.warps) <= id: return
            self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.warps) - 1, command=lambda: self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
        elif self.event_type == "Trigger": #Build widgets for trigger
            if len(self.map.triggers) <= id: return
            self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.triggers) - 1, command=lambda: self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
        elif self.event_type == "Sign": #Build widgets for sign
            if len(self.map.signposts) <= id: return
            self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox = tkinter.Spinbox(self.event_edit_widget, from_=0, to=len(self.map.signposts) - 1, command=lambda: self._select_event(self.event_type, self.event_edit_type_dropdown.get()))
        else: 
            raise Exception("Unkown event type selected: " + self.event_type)
        #Push all common widgets to the ui
        self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tkinter.NW)
        self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.config(state="readonly")
        self.event_edit_widgets.append(self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox)
    #Update all widgets
    self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.config(state="normal")
    self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.insert(0, str(id))
    self.event_edit_widget_id_spinbox.config(state="readonly")
```

If I leave out the delete and insert part my spinbox works perfectly fine, the values I can choose between are of the range I want them to be. However when using delete and insert the spinbox seems to "lose" all memory of the range I specified and offers me some appearantly random (but deterministic) strings instead of a value range. Why does this occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying that with the above code, you can use the little arrow buttons of the spinbox to go outside of the range you've specified?

Comment: Yes, when i press the "up" Button i go from 0 to a random text that was not specified in the range and is not eve a number (the text i get is "Person").

Comment: What does `self._select_event` do?

Comment: Too long for comment, I edited the inital post.